# Can I integrate Find/Replace Ctrl+F in Eclipse to my own project E4 RCP

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, e4

I have created project which contains the test scripts PY files. I need to search for a string in PY files.
Can I use in my code the already available Find/Replace Ctrl+F in Eclipse....  such that I can search in my project exe file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a pure e4 RCP the normal Eclipse find/replace dialog `org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.FindReplaceDialog` cannot be used as it uses the old 3.x APIs.